# Is it possible to assign an int value greater than 255 to a char?

Tags: c++, integer, char, c++14, integer-overflow

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int f = 1;
    int s = 500;
    char d = 256; // This line gives me overflow error 
    char c = s;   // But it does not. 
    cout << d << endl;
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why can I assign an `int` greater than 255 to a `char`, but I cannot directly assign an integer literal greater than 255?

How does the direct assignment of a literal value vary from the assignment of a value using a variable?

Comment: Where does it happen that you cannot assign the 256 to d?

Comment: `char d=256` can be diagnosed at compile time, `char c=s` would be a runtime issue (as `s` is not `const`(`expr`)).

Comment: Which compiler are you using and what are your compiler flags? What errors and warnings are you getting from your compiler? Please add to your problem statement. I would expect some warnings that the `char` declarations have problems.

Comment: On platforms where `char` is more than 8-bits (or more than 9-bits if treated as signed), an `int` value of more than 255 to char is possible.  Otherwise, there will be bit slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the error message and the compiler/compiler version you are using?

Most likely this is a warning because according to the standard the behavior is well defined and should compile:

> 7.3.9 Integral conversions [conv.integral]
>
> 1 A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of
> another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be
> converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> 2 If the destination type is bool, see 7.3.15. If the source type is
> bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is
> converted to one.
>
> **3 Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type**
> **that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2^N, where N is the**
> **width of the destination type.**
>
> 4 The conversions allowed as integral promotions are excluded from the
> set of integral conversions.

Comment: Care: 2's complement for signed is C++20 only; question is tagged C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the assignment can be done, but the value will be incorrect so it should not be done.

**Compile Time Constant Check**

The compiler should execute a constant value overflow check at compile time and will provide a warning that assigning 256 to d will result in truncation of the value.

**Runtime Check**

There is no runtime check for this overflow condition when the s with a value of 500 is assigned to char c.  Even though the assignment is possible, it will result in c being an incorrect value.
Here is an updated version of your code showing the incorrect value.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int f = 1;
   int s = 500;
   char d = 256; // This line gives me overflow error 
   char c = s;   // But it does not. 
   cout << d << endl;
   cout << c << endl;
   int s_corrupt = c;
   cout << s_corrupt << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It is your responsibility to ensure runtime overflows don’t happen.